# getJSON not sending new request as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Given the following JavaScript, I'm having an issue sending a new request when the search term is changed by the user. It is supposed to only begin searching/displaying results after there are more than 3 characters entered. It currently only makes one search after the initial term of more than 3 characters, but does not send another request after that.

**jQuery**

```
$("#results-container").hide();
$("#global-search").keyup(function(e) {

  var q = $("#global-search").val();
  if (e.which == 13) {
    window.location.replace("/search?q=" + q);
  }

  //Only begin search with at least 3 characters.
  if (q.length > 3) {
    $("#results-container").show();
    ajax_search();
  }

  //Send search query
  function ajax_search() {
    $.getJSON("//search.url-to-rest-api.com?q=" + q, {},
      //Get results and make 'em look good
      function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //  $(".results").append("Results for <b> " + q + "</b>");
        $.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
          if (data.type === "Practice Area") {
            $(".practice-area-results").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"" + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
            if ($(".practice-area-results").val() == '') {
              $(".practice-area-results-header, .practice-area-results").empty();
            }
          }
        });
      });
  }  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row desktop-search">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="global-search" style="width:100%; position: fixed;" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
      <div id="results-container">
        <div class="search-results">
          <p class="practice-area-results-header">Practice Area</p>
          <div class="practice-area-results"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fno697qj/). Check browser console.

Comment: The issue is that the results of the search do not reflect the new search queries. It only shows the results for the first query. How can I render new results based on the new query each time?

Comment: If it only shows the results for the first query only, then it seems like same `q` is passed on every search. Please check the XHR tab to see what response are sent on every input in console. If `q` are different every time then the issue might be with `//search.url-to-rest-api.com` as it is sending same response to different queries. Check these issues.